# css grid or flex fit as many columns as possible without specifying item-width or amount of columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

My playground fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/r6h8m3qs/1/

All the solutions make assumptions on the amount of COLUMNS e.g. `grid-template-columns: repeat(1fr, 7)` or they make assumptions on the ITEMS-width:  `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));`

In my case:

- only the width of the container is set (eg `50vw`).
- I then want to fit as many columns with the with of the WIDEST ELEMENT.
- I don't know how many elements I will have.
- I don't know how wide the WIDEST ELEMENT will be.

Is there a dynamic solution to get something like the SECOND example in my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r6h8m3qs/1/) ?

```
<div class="container2">
  <div class="item2">123</div>
  <div class="item2">123456</div>
  <div class="item2">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item2">3</div>
  <div class="item2">12</div>
  <div class="item2">23</div>
  <div class="item2">56</div>
  <div class="item2">89</div>
  <div class="item2">4</div>
</div>
```

```css
.container2 {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 50vw;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(7ex, 1fr));
}
.item2 {
  display: inline;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<h3>
Desired result: Without knowing item2-width and amount of cols
</h3>

<div class="container2">
  <div class="item2">123</div>
  <div class="item2">123456</div>
  <div class="item2">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item2">3</div>
  <div class="item2">12</div>
  <div class="item2">23</div>
  <div class="item2">56</div>
  <div class="item2">89</div>
  <div class="item2">4</div>
</div>
(resize handle in the corner of div.container2)
```

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with flexbox but my general idea would be to loop through each child element and determine its `offsetWidth` or `clientWidth` depending on whether you want to take borders etc into account or not. Doing it this way you can dynamicly count the number of columns and determine the widest element. After that it's a simple matter of doing some math on how many columns would fit and set them dynamicly. Create an event listener for the `resize` event to run the code again on resize and you're done.

Comment: You will need a js solution for this - css cannot make all siblings as wide as the widest child.  As there is no js attempt, I am voting to close as off topic as too broad

Comment: IMO this should stay open.

Comment: As the answer is no, CSS can't do that without script, and as such too broad, I agree with Pete.